# Find out if mic permissions have been granted via Javascript without getUserMedia

Tags: webrtc

Is there a way to determine the current permission granted to media like camera or mic using Javascript? I would like to build an elegant interface where if it has not been granted, would like the user to click on a button (say with a mic image) so that I can call the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` so that the prompt appears and the permission sought. And in case the media is already granted, then I just call the above JS code and get the stream without an interface.

I checked available Questions on stackOverflow and it has not been answered (in case it is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices and check if you get the label attribute on the devices you want. This is only set if (persistent) permission has been granted.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. If a user has blocked the permission can we force that user to reconsider by calling the allow deny box? Or do we just give an appropriate message asking them to reset in the preferences?

Comment: you'll have to ask, browsers won't allow a (potentially annoying) website to bring the allow/deny box again.

Comment: Thanks @Philipp Hancke. Currently, I show an appropriate message on the error clause of he getMedia promise.